# selecting a single field from a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Lets say I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
dictionList = {1: {'Type': 'Cat', 'Legs': 4},
               2: {'Type': 'Dog', 'Legs': 4},
               3: {'Type': 'Bird', 'Legs': 2}}
```

Using a for loop I want to iterate through the list until I catch a dictionary with a `Type` field equal to `"Dog"`.
My best attempt was:

```
 for i in dictionList:
     if dictionList(i['Type']) == "Dog":
         print "Found dog!"
```

But that gets me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any ideas on how to properly do this?

Comment: That's not a list of dictionaries, that a dictionary of dictionaries

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `values` iterator for dictionaries:

```
for v in dictionList.values():
    if v['Type']=='Dog':
         print "Found a dog!"
```

EDIT: I will say though that in your original question you are asking to check the `Type` of a value in a dictionary, which is somewhat misleading. What you are requesting is the content of  a *value* called 'Type'. This may be a subtle difference to understanding what you want, but it is a rather large difference in terms of programming.

In Python, you should ever only RARELY need to type-check anything.

Comment: +1, but one small modification: since the OP is using Py2, `dict.items` builds a list - better to use `viewvalues`, or in 2.6 and prior `itervalues`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [itervalues()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=itervalues#dict.itervalues) to check your dictionary of dictionaries.

```
for val in dictionList.itervalues():
   if val['Type'] == 'Dog':
      print 'Dog Found'
      print val
```

gives:

```
Dog Found
{'Legs': 4, 'Type': 'Dog'}
```

no need to use `iter`/`iteritems`, simply examine the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> diction_list = {1: {'Type': 'Cat', 'Legs': 4},
            2: {'Type': 'Dog', 'Legs': 4},
            3: {'Type': 'Bird', 'Legs': 2}}
>>> any(d['Type'] == 'Dog' for d in diction_list.values())
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for i in dictionList.itervalues():
    if i['Type'] == "Dog":
        print "Found dog!"
```

The problem is that, in your example, `i` is the integer key. With itervalues, you grab the value at the key (aka the dictionary you are wanting to parse).

Comment: And what do think `dictionList(i['Type'])` will do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just using the wrong syntax...try this:

```
>>> a = {1: {"Type": "Cat", "Legs": 4}, 2: {"Type": "Dog", "Legs": 4}, 3: {"Type": "Bird", "Legs": 2}}
>>> for item in a:
...     if a[item].get("Type") == "Dog":
...             print "Got it"
```

Comment: never declare a variable as `dict`

Comment: No need for default argument to `get`, it is `None` if you leave it out.

Comment: crap. thanks for both fixes. didn't even think about dict, and forgot about default default for .get

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the values of `i`.  They are not what you think they are.  The way to do this is:

```
for key,  val in dictionList.items():
    #do stuff to val
```

Answer (score 0):

Access via keys would be preferable in a dictionary. In your case for both the dictionary objects.

```
for i in dictionList.keys():
    if dictionList[i]['Type'] == 'Dog':
        print i
```