# Easy for in iteration through a single field in a list of dicts in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have already seen [selecting a single field from a list of dictionaries in python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836763/selecting-a-single-field-from-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python), but that asks a different question from what I want to ask here.

Consider this example:

```
oldpaths = [
  {'dir': '/path3' },
  {'dir': '/path1' },
  {'dir': '/path2' },
  {'dir': '/path4' },
]

nowpaths = [
  '/path1',
  '/path2',
  '/path3',
  '/path5',
]

print("Check missing A:")
missp1=0
for idird in oldpaths:
  if idird['dir'] not in nowpaths:
    missp1+=1
    print(missp1, idird['dir'])

print("Check missing B:")
missp2=0
for idirs in nowpaths:
  found = False
  for idird in oldpaths:
    if idirs == idird['dir']:
      found = True
      break
  if not(found):
    missp2+=1
    print(missp2, idirs)
```

It prints, as expected:

```
Check missing A:
(1, '/path4')
Check missing B:
(1, '/path5')
```

However, note that in the first case, I can just say `if idird['dir'] not in nowpaths:` and be done with it - but in the second case, I have to make an explicit loop through the list of dicts, etc.

Is there an easier syntax than this for a list of dicts, if I can limit myself to looking up a single field in the dict only? I imagine something like `if idirs not in oldpaths['dir']:`, but that unfortunately fails with "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines

```
found = False
for idird in oldpaths:
    if idirs == idird['dir']:
        found = True
        break
if not(found):
```

Could be rewritten with a generator expression:

```
if not any(idirs == idird['dir'] for idird in oldpaths):
```

However, a more efficient solution (especially if you have many paths in `nowpaths`) would be to create a set of directories out of oldpaths (and to do so outside of the for loop):

```
olddirs = set(idird['dir'] for idird in oldpaths)
for idirs in nowpaths:
    if not idirs in olddirs:
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @DavidRobinson - appreciate the note on efficiency. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to make the code shorter:

```
print("Check missing B:")
missp2=0
for idirs in nowpaths:
  if idird not in [oldpath['dir'] for oldpath in oldpaths]:
    missp2+=1
    print(missp2, idirs)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @VaughnCato - good to keep in mind that list comprehension is usable here, too. Cheers!